# C# IsNull() and IsEqualTo() - Visual Studio doesn't recognise them in sample Dapper.net / Contrib code

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-rainbow

I'm sure I'm being really stupid here - but I'm getting into Dapper and contrib. Sample code includes lines like this:

```
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Get<User>(3).IsNull();

            var id = connection.Insert(new User { Name = "Adam", Age = 10 });
```

IsNull() is never recognised. Nor is IsEqualTo in the same context.

I have googled - nothing close, searched in object browsers - am using Dapper - and using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions; But it sill can't find it.

thx

Comment: What is the connection string?  It is in the project configuration settings which is an xml file.  The tag is "DefaultConnection".  You are connecting to a SQL Server and the name of the server is in the connection string and must be valid and match the instance of the server you are using.

Comment: the connection string is to a sql server instance - that works fine and isn't causing the error (I can insert data if i comment the isNull line) - I would just like to know where IsNull and IsEqualTo come from

Comment: Right click on GET and then select 'go to definition'.

Comment: It's in Dapper.Contrib.Extensions

Comment: Boolean status = connection.Get<User>(3).IsNull();  I suspect that IsNull will create an exception which is handled by the 'using' so the application doesn't halt when the connection isn't defined in the configuration file.

Comment: OK but IsNull has a red line under it - the solution will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are actually methods from the testing framework that is being used. They are actually assertions; the `IsNull()` is *asserting* that the value on the left is `null`, and throwing an exception otherwise. The `IsEqualTo` is *asserting* that the value on the left is equal to the value passed to the method, and throwing an exception otherwise.

You don't need those methods for real code. I guess that the example has been lifted from a test method, where it is being used to confirm the state of the data before and after the insert.

It comes to mind that `AssertNull` and `AssertEqualTo` might be better names!

The code is in [`Assert.cs`](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/Assert.cs); they *could* also be invoked via:

```
Assert.IsNull(connection.Get<User>(3));
...
Assert.IsEqualTo(someObj.SomeProp, 42);
```

etc, in which case the intent would be more obvious. The fact that they are extension methods hides a little bit of detail in this case (specifically, the fact that the declaring type is `Assert`).

Comment: +1 We have similar methods in our internal framework that helps ReSharper flag code more correctly, that are compiled away in release builds, but under no circumstance should production code contain a reference to a unit-test framework... unless you're building code that executes tests.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen the methods in question aren't even part of the core library project; they are in the test project only. You can't reference the test project since we don't ship it. I agree with your point - it just doesn't really apply here :)

Comment: My point was that I agreed with you :) It got lost in translation from my head. More coffee I guess.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen gotta love that `[Conditional]` usage, though (I'm assuming that is what you are describing, although it could also be a `partial` method that lacks an implementation in release); very powerful for debug-only code - far prettier than filling the code with `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: No, it's conditional :) The entire method is empty save for `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` and `[ContractAnnotation("false => halt")]` or `[ContractAnnotation("null => halt")]`.

Comment: thx - so this is some arbitrary / custom testing framework - and to get this to work I need to just remove those lines as they are for demonstration purposes only? (or is there a common framework I can reference in a using statement to just make the examples run?).

Comment: @niico you can copy/paste that `Assert.cs` to make the examples just run :) There's some back-story to the `Assert.cs` class - IIRC I ended up writing the test rig from scratch while stuck at an airport for a few hours without any network access, hence I couldn't pull down any of the usual suspects; as it happens, though, it has let us move between multiple frameworks without having to change the code. As you can see, the `Assert.cs` is currently implemented using xunit, but it has been nunit, and "other" at various points. It is essentially an accidental abstraction over the test API

Comment: Interesting story :D I've added Asserts.cs - I get this error on  Xunit.Assert.Equal "Error CS0012 The type 'IEnumerable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'." (i added that to web.config & tried adding a reference to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\System.Runtime.dll" - neither fixed it). I downloaded the entire solution - stuck building for 2 hours.

Comment: @niico if it was me, I would just comment out the calls to these methods that aren't doing anything useful - anything that looks like an assertion probably isn't needed